# How to show only updated nodes in VIEWS

Tags: 7, views

I am creating a **View** in **Drupal 7** for a particular content type.
I want to **add filter to show nodes which are updated**. When I am adding Node Update Date field, it is asking for operator and Value to compare with. But I can not provide Updated date of each node.

Then I also tried **hook_views_query_alter** to alter the query. When I am adding Query Value to node.created field it take it as a string or you can say Value.

Can someone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use hook_views_query_alter to load only nodes which have node.updated value equal to NULL or ''.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a filter available called `Content: Has New Content` specifically for this use case.

```
Content: Has new content
Show only content that is new or updated.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sort option and Sort by Content: Updated date in the views.